# Is memset() more efficient than for loop in C?

Tags: c, performance, memset

Is `memset()`  more efficient than `for` loop.

Considering this code:

```
char x[500];
memset(x,0,sizeof(x));
```

And this one:

```
char x[500];
for(int i = 0 ; i < 500 ; i ++) x[i] = 0;
```

Which one is more efficient and why? Is there any special instruction in hardware to do block level initialization.

Comment: Yes. No. Maybe. It depends. The only way to get a useful answer is to analyze and profile it *in your environment*. Which one is faster on my compiler, in my program, on my computer, tells you nothing useful.

Comment: Compile both and benchmark them. The answer depends on what kind of computer you're using, what compiler you use, what standard library you use, the size of the block you're trying to change, the phase of the moon...

Comment: @Chris: You likely don't need to even go that far.  Just peeking at the assembly output should be sufficient.

Comment: Why bother investigating?  Unless there is data to show otherwise (you are failing your perf goals and investigation points to this section of code), this piece of code is likely not a hotspot, and you should just go for as simple, readable, and maintainable code possible.

Comment: @Ed S. - Not everyone can read assembly. Everyone can read numbers. (Well, everyone who programs.)

Comment: If you have a compiler that doesn't substitute that loop with memset() then you should find another compiler.

Comment: @Chris: Ummmm.... they should probably learn then.  I guess I'm a 27 year old dinosaur, but I have a problem with so-called "engineers" who can't read basic assembly... I don't mean to imply that one shouldn't use a profiler, but for such a trivial comparison it should be unnecessary.

Comment: @Ed S. - If you program in C extensively, then I agree. If you're a web programmer who doesn't really need to work with anything lower-level than Python, meh. I'll never say "you don't need to learn something," but in some contexts knowledge of assembly may not be very useful (and in some contexts knowledge of the operating system's internal workings may be _more_ useful).

Comment: @Chris: And that is why so many web guys (and gals) that I have come into contact with write applications that are much slower than they should be.  Not necessarily because they can't read assembly, but because they never really learned the performance characteristics of the data structures they use and how their high level code may be executed when it is turned into machine code.  I digress though, that's a discussion for another place and time.

Comment: @Ed S. - I don't disagree with you - I'd love it if Notch learned C/assembly/CS theory/whatever and made Minecraft run at a consistent speed.

Comment: @Chris: Haha, yes please, me too :)

Comment: And if you only need to do it once, do it at the definition: `char x[500] = {0};`, which won't have any effect on running speed but makes the code look nicer to me.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Most certainly, `memset` will be much faster than that loop. Note how you treat one *character* at a time, but those functions are so optimized that set several bytes at a time, even using, when available, MMX and SSE instructions.

I think the paradigmatic example of these optimizations, that go unnoticed usually, is the GNU C library `strlen` function. One would think that it has at least O(n) performance, but it actually has O(n/4) or O(n/8) depending on the architecture (yes, I know, in big O() will be the same, but you actually get an *eighth* of the time). How? Tricky, but nicely: [strlen](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/lib/libc/string/strlen.c?view=markup).

Comment: Any optimizing compiler will replace the for loop with an optimal sequence (which may be a call to memset).

Comment: Also, for it to be "much faster" is not guaranteed, even if the compiler emits sub-optimal code for the loop.  500 is not really that high of a number, and if a soft or hard page fault is incurred, that will greatly outweigh the cost of the loop itself.

Comment: @Stephen Canon: Heh. I was compiling a C library with clang/LLVM and it replaced the library's memset for loop with a call to memset. Oops! Deep recursion.

Comment: @Michael: those faults are out of the question. Of course, they can happen, but when the performance of making, say, 500/8 assigns is slower than doing 500 assignations to 0? Also, I think the OP used 500 as an example.

Comment: @Diego it's not a question of 500/8 assigns being slower or faster than 500 assigns to 0.  Micro-benchmarks like this are rarely useful due to other effects in the system.  On a modern processor, the difference between only the comparisons will probably be on the order of 62 cycles versus 500 cycles.  What I'm suggesting is if you incur a hard page fault on the order of 10 million cycles while running the code, the 438 cycles you saved are just noise.

Comment: Also, unless this chunk of code executes hundreds of thousands of times each second, a 438 cycle difference will not be user perceptible and you're wasting your time optimizing non-issues.

Comment: @Michael: then why micro-optimize? :)

Comment: @Diego: It sounds like we are in agreement :)  Micro-optimizations are best left to the compiler which can apply them wholesale to your entire codebase.  Hand micro-optimization is appropriate when you've identifying a piece of code as greatly impacting your performance and you cannot identify any algorithmic improvements.  My suggestion is to stick to memset since it is one line of code versus 4, which I think is more readable.

Comment: @Michael: I agree with you in some points... Anyway, I was trying to be sarcastic... :) I agree in one line vs. four lines. Also, I'd say use it because this is what it is there for. *But* micro-optimizations are important, even at this level. Yes, here we have 500 elements, and a function that maybe in this program is called once. But what if afterwards that function is used as a part of other computation and get called one million times? Then those 400 cycles are 400 seconds...

Comment: @Richard Pennington: `-fno-builtin-memset`.

Comment: It is wrong. O is the worst performance, and that is O(n) – consider string of length 1... Ω is the best performance and it is Ω(n/8). That is for clarity. :)

Comment: Sometimes O() is used instead of o() (lower case sigma). But we all understand here that the difference between both is the constants, that are not considered in the big O.

Comment: Is it somehow possible that, multiple processor split memset among different processors... any idea ?

Comment: The real bottleneck is memory access... So multiple processors won't make it faster. Alas, you have to coordinate them, and memory copying is a somewhat fast operation compared with coordination.

Comment: Link is broken. What are you trying to illustrate?

Comment: @SOFe It's fixed now. The implementation given uses a trick to read null-terminated strings 4 or 8 bytes at a time and can use a simple function to determine if any of those bytes contains a null terminator. That way it doesn't have to check each byte individually.

Answer (score 43):

Well, why don't we take a look at the generated assembly code, full optimization under VS 2010.

```
char x[500];
char y[500];
int i;      

memset(x, 0, sizeof(x) );   
  003A1014  push        1F4h  
  003A1019  lea         eax,[ebp-1F8h]  
  003A101F  push        0  
  003A1021  push        eax  
  003A1022  call        memset (3A1844h)
```

And your loop...

```
char x[500];
char y[500];
int i;    

for( i = 0; i < 500; ++i )
{
    x[i] = 0;

      00E81014  push        1F4h  
      00E81019  lea         eax,[ebp-1F8h]  
      00E8101F  push        0  
      00E81021  push        eax  
      00E81022  call        memset (0E81844h)  

      /* note that this is *replacing* the loop, 
         not being called once for each iteration. */
}
```

So, under this compiler, the generated code is exactly the same.  `memset` is fast, and the compiler is smart enough to know that you are doing the same thing as calling `memset` once anyway, so it does it for you.

If the compiler actually left the loop as-is then it would likely be slower as you can set more than one byte size block at a time (i.e., you could unroll your loop a bit at a minimum.  You can assume that `memset` will be *at least* as fast as a naive implementation such as the loop.  Try it under a debug build and you will notice that the loop is not replaced.

That said, it depends on what the compiler does for you. Looking at the disassembly is always a good way to know exactly what is going on.

Comment: Interesting, my version did not result in the loop being converted to memset, but that is probably because for my test, the loop operated on a global (otherwise the entire loop was removed as being unnecessary.)

Comment: @Michael: I added a couple of calls to `printf` using `x` and `y` to ensure that they weren't completely optimized away as they are unused.  It is of course compiler and platform dependent to some degree, but any half way decent optimizing compiler should get rid of the loop with optimizations turned on.

Comment: even memset() vs array initialization (Ex: a[n]={0}) takes same code it looks. Advantage of of memset is that array size can be a variable, which is not possible with initialization. Am I right?

Comment: How do you inspect the "disassembly".

Comment: @young_souvlaki: In VS? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-use-the-disassembly-window?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 13):

It really depends on the compiler and library.  For older compilers or simple compilers, memset may be implemented in a library and would not perform better than a custom loop.

For nearly all compilers that are worth using, memset is an intrinsic function and the compiler will generate optimized, inline code for it.

Others have suggested profiling and comparing, but I wouldn't bother.  Just use memset.  Code is simple and easy to understand.  Don't worry about it until your benchmarks tell you this part of code is a performance hotspot.

Answer (score 9):

The answer is 'it depends'.  `memset` MAY be more efficient, or it may internally use a for loop. I can't think of a case where `memset` will be less efficient.  In this case, it may turn into a more efficient for loop: your loop iterates 500 times setting a bytes worth of the array to 0 every time.  On a 64 bit machine, you could loop through, setting 8 bytes (a long long) at a time, which would be almost 8 times quicker, and just dealing with the remaining 4 bytes (500%8) at the end.

EDIT:

in fact, this is what `memset` does in glibc:

http://repo.or.cz/w/glibc.git/blob/HEAD:/string/memset.c

As Michael pointed out, in certain cases (where the array length is known at compile time), the C compiler can inline `memset`, getting rid of the overhead of the function call.  Glibc also has assembly optimized versions of `memset` for most major platforms, like amd64:

http://repo.or.cz/w/glibc.git/blob/HEAD:/sysdeps/x86_64/memset.S

Comment: I can think of a situation where `memset` will be less efficient: a compiler that can't inline (well).

Comment: I imagine if both the second two arguments were known at compile time most humans would be hard pressed to equal the compiler generated code.

Answer (score 3):

Good compilers will recognize the for loop and replace it with either an optimal inline sequence or a call to memset.  They will also replace memset with an optimal inline sequence when the buffer size is small.

In practice, with an optimizing compiler the generated code (and therefore performance) will be identical.

Comment: Can you provide a citation?

Comment: Try it and see with any good optimizing compiler (e.g. 
http://goo.gl/2mWsxq).  I'm not sure what there is to "cite" here.

Comment: Academic citations are always important, even if just grey literature.

Answer (score 2):

Agree with above. It depends. But, for sure memset is faster or equal to the for-loop. If you are uncertain of your environment or too lazy to test, take the safe route and go with memset.

Comment: Please specify which one you mean by "above."

Answer (score 1):

Other techniques like [loop unrolling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling) which reduce the number of loops can also be used. The code of *memset()* can mimic the famous [duff's device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device#Performance):

```c
void *duff_memset(char *to, int c, size_t count)
{
    size_t n;
    char *p = to;
    n = (count + 7) / 8;
    switch (count % 8) {
    case 0: do { *p++ = c;
    case 7:      *p++ = c;
    case 6:      *p++ = c;
    case 5:      *p++ = c;
    case 4:      *p++ = c;
    case 3:      *p++ = c;
    case 2:      *p++ = c;
    case 1:      *p++ = c;
            } while (--n > 0);
    }
    return to;
}
```

Those tricks used to enhancing the execution speed in the past. But on modern architectures this tends to increase the code size and increase cache misses.

So, it is quite impossible to say which implementation is faster as it depends on the quality of the compiler optimizations, the ability of the C library to take advantage of special hardware instructions, the amount of data you are operating on and the features of the underlying operating system (page faults management, TLB misses, Copy-On-Write).

For example, in the glibc, the implementation of *memset()* as well as various other "copy/set" functions like *bzero()* or *strcpy()* are architecture dependent to take advantage of various optimized hardware instructions like [SSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions) or [AVX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions).