# Passing parameters to objects whilst simultaneously instantiating an array

Tags: java, arrays, parameters

I have an array of `Object` and wondered if I could pass parameters whilst simultaneously instantiating the array.

For example:

```
theArray = new Object(20, 20, 20)[30];
```

I want to avoid looping through each element and passing parameters to them after the array has been created if I can help it.

I know the above syntax isn't correct, but it illustrates what I'm trying to achieve.

Thanks for your responses!

Comment: No, you can't. But look at the `Arrays` class for alternatives.

Comment: You might be able to dosomething like theArray = {new Object(20, 20, 20), new Object(20, 20, 20)...} but would still have to type them all out.  Not entirely sure this would work, but worth a shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Arrays.fill()` to avoid looping.

**Example**

Create an array with 30 instances of MyClass that all have the values 20, 20, 20.

```
MyClass[] theArray = new MyClass[30];
Arrays.fill(theArray, new MyClass(20,20,20));
```

Comment: Nice...didn't know about that.  Can't think of a use for it for what I'm doing, but it's good to know if the need arises.

Comment: @BobStout You can't think of a use for an array of 30 identical objects? You aren't very imaginative.

Comment: I mainly deal with thousands of objects, all different, all interrelated.  My imagination is currently occupied.  :)

Comment: This is almost what I'm looking for. I guess it's a lack in my understanding of the task at hand. This will provide all the objects in the array with the same properties. However I need them all to have the same properties, with a few exceptions. So I guess I will have to loop!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
theArray = {20, 20, 20};
```

This means that you have an array with size of 3.

Answer (score -1):

If you're just trying to keep your main code clean, shuffle it off to a function:

```
theArray = getObjects(30);
...
private Object[] getObjects(int numObjects){
    Object[] returnObjects = new Object[30];
    for(int x=0; x<numObjects;x++){
    //etc, etc, etc
    }
    return returnObjects;
}
```

Comment: It's more about performance, I don't want to have to loop through each element in the array and pass parameters to them if I can just do that at the point where I instantiate the array.

Comment: John's answer is best for you then.  Check out odys's answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128737/fastest-way-to-set-all-values-of-an-array

Comment: If you're going to downvote the answer, at least be a man and explain why.