# Can this code of on the fly objects creation be optimized?

Tags: java

I have a method which accepts a class parameter.
I need to create a list of this class objects for any kind of a class.
Each class may have a constructor with various number of parameters.

This is what I managed to get so far.
It works, but obviously it is not generic enough.
Is there a more generic code for this code?

```
public List<Object> convertSeparatedListToJsonList(String pipedStr, String separatorRegex, Class c){

        try {

                Class<?> cCtor = Class.forName(c.getTypeName());

                List<String> valuesList = Stream.of(pipedStr.split(separatorRegex)).map(String::trim).collect(Collectors.toList());
                int valuesNumber = valuesList.size();

                switch (valuesNumber) {
                    case 1 -> {
                        Constructor<?> ctor = cCtor.getConstructor(String.class);
                        return List.of(ctor.newInstance(valuesList.get(0)));
                    }
                    case 2 -> {
                        Constructor<?> ctor = cCtor.getConstructor(String.class, String.class);
                        return List.of(ctor.newInstance(valuesList.get(0), valuesList.get(1)));
                    }
                    case 4 -> {
                        Constructor<?> ctor = cCtor.getConstructor(String.class, String.class, String.class, String.class);
                        return List.of(ctor.newInstance(valuesList.get(0), valuesList.get(1), valuesList.get(2), valuesList.get(3)));
                    }
                    case 5 -> {
                        Constructor<?> ctor = cCtor.getConstructor(String.class, String.class, String.class, String.class, String.class);
                        return List.of(ctor.newInstance(valuesList.get(0), valuesList.get(1), valuesList.get(2), valuesList.get(3), valuesList.get(4)));
                    }
                    default -> {
                        return new ArrayList<>();
                    }
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | NoSuchMethodException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                log.error(e.getMessage());
                return new ArrayList<>();
            }
}
```

My goal: to generalize the switch part for all list sizes.

Comment: This looks kind of weird to me. You always return a list of one thing regardless of what `valuesNumber` is?

Comment: What do you mean by "one thing"? I pass the specific class as an argument to the method, and return a list of this class objects. Hope it is clearer now :)

Comment: Varargs in Java are just syntactic sugar for arrays. This means that you can pass an array to  `ctor.newInstance()` instead of separate varargs. Just create a `String[]`, fill it with the appropriate values, and pass it to `ctor.newInstance` - no `switch` necessary and it will work for any number of values. (The same for `cCtor.getConstructor()`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this should work:

```
public List<Object> convertSeparatedListToJsonList(String pipedStr, String separatorRegex, Class<?> cCtor){
    try {
        List<String> valuesList = Stream.of(pipedStr.split(separatorRegex)).map(String::trim).collect(Collectors.toList());
        int valuesNumber = valuesList.size();

        Class<?>[] constructorParameters = new Class<?>[valuesNumber];
        Arrays.fill(constructorParameters, String.class);
        Constructor<?> ctor = cCtor.getConstructor(constructorParameters);
        return List.of(ctor.newInstance(valuesList.toArray()));
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
        return List.of();
    }
}
```

I've changed the last parameter to not use a raw type, and I've removed the use of `Class.forName`, which seems redundant.

To call `getConstructor`, you can create an array of size `valuesNumber` and `fill` it with `String.class`, then pass that array.

Similarly, to call `newInstance`, you can just convert `valuesList` to an array.

This works because variable arity parameters (e.g. the parameter of `getConstructor`) have array types as their formal parameter types, and Java prefers a non-variable arity invocation over a variable arity invocation. This means that `ctor.newInstance(valuesList.toArray())` will actually be understood as "call the constructor with the parameters in this array", rather than "call the constructor with the array as the single parameter".

Answer (score 5):

That `getConstructor` method call is already taking an array of classes. Same with `newInstance` so all you need to do is initialize an array of size `valuesNumber` that is filled with String.class and then convert your valuesList to an array. Here are some useful links:

[Fastest way to set all values of an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128737/fastest-way-to-set-all-values-of-an-array)

[Convert list to array in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9572795/convert-list-to-array-in-java)