# How to populate all elements of a declared variable with the value of 1. In Java

Tags: java, arrays, variables

```
public int[] board1 = new int [20];
```

This is the defined variable.
Also does the value of 1 affect this code?

```
for (int i=-1;i<2;i++)
        board1[i]=1;
```

[image: Task]

Comment: Wouldn't you need to loop through the whole array? So, `i = 0` and `i < arraylength`.

Comment: `Arrays.fill(board1, 1)` - not sure what you're trying to do with the `for-loop`, but I'm sure it'll break

Comment: I don't understand the question. But, `for (int i=-1;i<2;i++) board1[i]=1;` is sure to throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: You seem to have some misconceptions about arrays. How did you come up with the for loop? You could read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: "does the value of 1 affect this code" What do you mean?

Comment: I did post the task my teacher gave me, if that helps.

Comment: So you were given a for loop with deliberately incorrect bounds and you need to figure out the correct ones?

Comment: Images of text are [not well received](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) here. Please edit the question again, replacing the image with actual text. Use copy-and-paste to ensure accuracy. And indicate which are lines 22 and 25.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you're confused about the array bounds. I don't know if you have experience with other languages (like C) where this is not an option, but in Java the size of an array is stored as a member, so to iterate over the elements of an array we can do so like this:

```
int[] foo; //foo is just an array. this works for arrays of any type
           // but i've just written 'int' because that's what you're using
for (int i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
    foo[i] = 1; //we can set the value of the array at all points
}
```

...and it will work for all arrays, because they all start at `0` and end at `.length - 1`

There is also for-each syntax, but this cannot be used to mutate the array (unless the array is of a class that has methods to mutate its internal state)

```
for (int x: foo) {
    System.out.println(x); //this will print each element of 'foo' in order,
                           //but the variable within this loop, x, is a shallow copy of that element of foo,
                           // so we cannot mutate it
}
```

lastly, as others have mentioned, there is `Arrays.fill()`. [This just does the same thing we've done with the loop](https://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/Arrays-source.html),  but wraps it up nice into a single method call. Whether you use this or not is about style and taste (I've had jobs where they didn't want us to use it, but I personally prefer it).

If you need to set the array more quickly and would like the JVM and compiler to utilise special CPU instructions to do so, [there *may* be a to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128737/fastest-way-to-set-all-values-of-an-array), but it's best in most cases to use one the three forms I showed.

Comment: Most Java environments are based on OpenJDK, not GNU Classpath. But looking at the source code is pointless anyway, as [explained here](https://psy-lob-saw.blogspot.com/2015/04/on-arraysfill-intrinsics-superword-and.html). In short, just use `Arrays.fill(…)`. In the worst case, it does the same as the loop, but is still simpler and it may be even faster. I don’t know what the 3rd solution ought to be when you say “use one the three forms I showed”. In your answer, there are only two variants of doing what the question asked for.