# Faster : Zeroing cython array

Tags: cython, fill, zero

I'm using this to cleanup array in Cython

```
cdef void fill(DTYPE[:] ary):
    cdef int i, size = len(ary)
    for i in range(size): ary[i] = 0
```

is there a faster way ?

---

they seems to have it,cdef'd

[source](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/efdf996dced075682d86b7e53a12b56b5ebfea38/Cython/Includes/cpython/array.pxd)

```
cdef inline void zero(array self):
    """ set all elements of array to zero. """
    memset(self.data.as_chars, 0, Py_SIZE(self) * self.ob_descr.itemsize)
```

---

generated code :

```
    cdef array.array rows
    array.zero(rows)

__pyx_f_7cpython_5array_zero(__pyx_v_rows);
```

but if :

```
    cdef float[::1] rows
```

@DavidW example generates a cleaner version i.e. for-loop

---

summarized it [here](https://myriad.website/cython-tips-and-tricks/) and added some more tricks

Comment: I _think_ `memset` can be used, based on [the docs](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/array.html). Firstly  import  it `from libc.string cimport memset` and then something like `memset(ary, 0, size*sizeof(ary))` or `memset(ary.data.as_voidptr, 0, size*sizeof(ary))`. Not quite sure though

Comment: Though, [according to this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7367803/13132315), it seems that `memset` yields the same assembly instructions as the `for` loop if the compiler is configured properly.

Comment: `memset` relies on the array being contiguous, which you don't guarantee here.

Answer (score 1):

```
cdef void fill(double[:] ary):
    ary[:] = 0
```

compiles. It's certainly the clearest way and is converted to a straightforward looking C loop. It also means that you don't have to worry about turning off boundschecking and negative indexing.

It'll be helped a little if you declare `ary` as contiguous (`double[::1] ary`), although of course that restricts the types of arrays it can do. If you aren't prepared to only accept contiguous arrays, then you should not use `memset` since it'll be zeroing stuff outside your array.